# Sort files based on day of week

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I have several files:

```
Friday.log
Monday.log
Tuesday.log
Saturday.log
Sunday.log
Thursday.log
Tuesday.log
Wednesday.log
```

I want to put their filename without .log and contents into one file but in order of day of week starting with Monday to Sunday. I have a command that will put them together without .log but not in order:

```
awk 'FNR==1{sub(/[.][^.]*$/"", FILENAME); print FILENAME} 1' *.log > all.log
```

That gives me :

```
Friday
... Friday contents
Monday
... Monday contents
Tuesday
... Tuesday contents
Saturday
... Saturday contents
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can "play" with the `%u` parameter of `date` to know the day of the week of any given date:

```
$ date -d"last Sunday" +%u
7
```

However, and since this list is pretty much stable, why don't you just hardcode it in an array?

```
#!/bin/bash

days=('Monday' 'Tuesday' 'Wednesday' 'Thursday' 'Friday' 'Saturday' 'Sunday')

for day in "${days[@]}"
do
    echo "$day"
    cat "$day.log"
done > all.log
```

Comment: My problem is i have to it with "one command". So how would i use %u and date?

Comment: @SpencerMichealBell I gave a hint, try to do some research yourself. Also, [so] is not about showing how to do this with that constraints, but about how to do it in the better way. I don't think having a one command here makes much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

`perl -le 'for $day qw(Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday) {print $day; system("cat $day.log")}'`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up actually doing something with touching all the files. Then ls -t piped into the awk commmand

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing:

```
touch Thursday.log && touch Wednesday.log && touch Tuesday.log && touch Monday.log && ls -t | xargs -i awk 'FNR==1{sub(/[.][^.]*$/"", FILENAME); print FILENAME} 1' {} > all.log
```